# Which should I use, -awakeFromNib or -viewDidLoad?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I recently had a problem in my app where some of the subviews I was creating in a UIViewController subclass's  `-awakeFromNib` method were disappearing from the view. After some poking around I found that moving the code I had put in `-awakeFromNib` to `-viewDidLoad` solved the problem. Seems that `-awakeFromNib` gets called only once when the UIViewController is unarchived from the nib, and `-viewDidLoad` gets called every time the view is unarchived.

So what's the best practice? It looks like UIViewController's `-awakeFromNib` shouldn't be adding any views to the view, that kind of stuff should be done in `-viewDidLoad`. Am I understanding this correctly? Or am I more confused than I thought?

Comment: remember, viewDidLoad only applies to VIEW CONTROLLERS, not views as such.  awakeFromNib actually applies to "everything" since it is part of NSObject. and remember, if dealing with a view do NOT run, say, animations in awakeFromNib because the view is still very likely being animated in to position, etc.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` is called when the **controller** itself is unarchived from a nib. `viewDidLoad` is called when the **view** is created/unarchived. This distinction is especially important when the controller's view is stored in a separate nib file.

Comment: iOS devs beware [behaviour on iOS is different](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2196262/618653)

Comment: In the spec of `awakeFromNib`, "it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established", so which outlet is it? Is it the view outlet?

Comment: what's the difference between created & unarchived? does unarchived refer to files made in a non-programmatical ie (storyboard and xib) way? and created refer to pure programmatic?

Comment: Unarchived means the view came from a storyboard/xib. Created means it was instantiated programmatically.

Answer (score 24):

Also important is that the `awakeFromNib` function will never be called after recovering from memory warning. But, the `viewDidLoad` function will be called.

Comment: is it still valid in 2016?

Comment: @khunshan No, views are no longer unloaded automagically by iOS like they used to be.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's correct. You shouldn't really rely on `awakeFromNib` to do that kind of tasks.

`awakeFromNib` is similar to an event that's called after deserialization in .NET. `viewDidLoad` is similar to `Load` event in .NET.

If you are familiar with the concepts from .NET, this should be enough, I think.

Answer (score 7):

I'll try to answer by giving an example:

If define `customCell` class and `customCell.xib` file, and then load the cell by using
 `- (NSArray *)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options`, **awakeFromNib** gets called when the objects in the xib are unarchived.

If you define a `customViewController`, then when the `customViewController` is created using `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil`. **viewDidLoad** will get called when it's loaded into view hierarchy.

Some related confusing methods:

- (void)loadView; This is where subclasses should create their custom view hierarchy if they aren't using a nib. If you don't specify a nib name, then loadView will attempt to load a nib whose name is the same as your view controller's class. If no such nib exists, then you must either call -setView: before -view is invoked, or override the -loadView method to set up your views programatically. -loadView should never be called directly.
- (void)viewDidLoad:  Called after the view has been loaded. For viewControllers created in code, this is after -loadView. For view controllers unarchived from a nib, this is after the view is set.

Answer (score -1):

For a ViewController, IBOutlets are available in viewDidLoad()

Here **stackView** represents an IBOutlet in a ViewController, **stackView** is nil in awakeFromNib, but it has been instantiated when viewDidLoad() is called.

[image: IBOutlets state in awakeFromNib() vs IBOutlet state in viewDidLoad()]

Comment: you are missing a super.awakeFromNib and super.viewDidLoad calls. Once super.awakeFromNib is called then all IBOutlets of type Object will be initiated except the view and IBOutlets which are aliases to the view subviews.