# Buildtime Canvas Pod xCode issue | missing a [super awakeFromNib] call || from CSAnimationView.m file

Tags: swift, xcode, canvas, awakefromnib

I just added the canvas pod (through cocoapods) and I can see the files in my workspace just fine, and I was able to "import Canvas" into my ViewController.swift. But I am getting a semantic build time error that the file CSAnimationView.m is possibly missing a method [super awakeFromNib][errorscreenshot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwp6D.png)

```
/*
* This file is part of the Canvas package.
* (c) Canvas <usecanvas@gmail.com>
*
* For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
* file that was distributed with this source code.
*/

#import "CSAnimationView.h" @implementation CSAnimationView

- (void)awakeFromNib {
if (self.type && self.duration && ! self.pauseAnimationOnAwake) {[self startCanvasAnimation];
}
}

- (void)startCanvasAnimation {

    Class <CSAnimation> class = [CSAnimationclassForAnimationType:self.type];

    [class performAnimationOnView:self duration:self.durationdelay:self.delay];

    [super startCanvasAnimation];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since:

1) the library you are trying to add, "Canvas", is 3 and more years is not being updated, latest version is 0.1.2, see here: https://github.com/CanvasPod/Canvas/releases

2) Xcode >= 8 requires [super awakeFromNib], please read here: 
[Calling awakeFromNib of superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804623/calling-awakefromnib-of-superclass) and here:

> You must call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent
>   classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they
>   require. Although the default implementation of this method does
>   nothing, many UIKit classes provide non-empty implementations. You may
>   call the super implementation at any point during your own
>   awakeFromNib method.

The only way to build it, is adding manually the branch master and fix by yourself the issue(s)

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the answer. Perfect.