# UIKit - awakeFromNib if not implemented

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, awakefromnib

From Xcode 8 update it just noticed that, for `UITableViewCell`'s `awakeFromNib` method with no content inside(automatically created while adding custom cell class with xib file), giving me the following warning.

> Method possibly missing a [super awakeFromNib] call

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446391/3743322), got idea why should we implement super class methods. But I need to know what will be the impact if we are not implementing this method.

Is there any performance issues or any other kind of issues, in case if `awakeFromNib` in any of the subclasses of UIKit classes is not implemented?

Comment: In the link you provided is clearly stated, that `awakeFromNib` default implementation does nothing, so in this particular case you might not call `super awakeFromNib`, but in general it's a good practice calling `super` to `UIKit` superclasses when overriding methods, because Apple at any time might add something important to default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In the link you provided is clearly stated, that `awakeFromNib` default implementation does nothing, so in this particular case you might not call `[super awakeFromNib]`, but in general it's a good practice calling `super` to `UIKit` superclasses when overriding methods, because Apple might at any time add something important to default implementation.