# Setting Delegate in awakeFromNib

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, viewdidload, awakefromnib

I have a ViewController in Interface Builder that has a TableViewController embedded in it (I reuse the functionality of the TableViewController elsewhere).  I need to set a delegate in the TabelViewController back to the UIViewController it is embedded in so that I can use the NavigationController of the UIViewController (click on row in embedded TableViewController, new ViewController appears....).

I've got a delegate to make this all work, the only problem I have is where to set the delegate.  I had read that `awakeFromNib` gets called once a nib is read in and all IBOutlets have been set (the embedded TableViewController is an IBOutlet). I can step through the code and see that this function is called when the app first launches.  However, when I later call the delegate (when a row is clicked), the delegate is `null`. If I set the delegate in `viewDidLoad`, everything works great.

Any ideas why awakeFromNib isn't working? Should I be doing this in viewDidLoad anyway?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about why your awakeFromNib method is not working properly here: [Why won't my awakeFromNib fire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588813/why-wont-my-awakefromnib-fire)

The viewDidLoad method is a perfect place for setting the UITableViewDelegate no actual benefits from setting it in other methods.