# What's the order of execution for UIViewController loading methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

It's clear to me the difference between `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, etc.

What's not clear is where in the execution of a `UIViewController` code `awakeFromNib` stays.

[I've found a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588813/why-wont-my-awakefromnib-fire/2196262#2196262) about the `awakeFromNib` method, but it's still not clear to me...

Can you provide the correct order of execution for those methods?

Comment: Add log statements in each method an check yourself. Alternatively use the debugger in combination with break points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

You can check all this information directly from Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html
I recommend yo u to read It.
Hope It helps.