# awakeFromNib not get called in UIViewController subclass with xib file

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nib, awakefromnib

Maybe you see this question is kind of duplicated question. But I want to ask a new question because the other questions are ancient. I'm working with iOS 10.3 by Xcode 8.3.1.

In my case, I subclass UIViewController using xib, all thing seem fine, but I see that the function `awakeFromNib()` not get called, that I guessed it must be called. I tried with several projects, even the function `awakeAfter(using aDecoder: NSCoder)` get called, but not `awakeFromNib()`. Is there any reason in iOS sdk?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post how you initialise the view controller object and a bit more detail how's the structure in your xib?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my awakeFromNib fire?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588813/why-wont-my-awakefromnib-fire)

Comment: Can you please explain how you load your UIViewController's subclass?

Comment: Where ever you are loading it from, is it getting created properly?