# InitWithCoder never called for Cocoa NSView based class

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, initwithcoder, initwithframe

I create a `XIB`.

I create this class called `MyCustomView` and assign it to the `XIB`'s File Owner.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if (self) [self load];
  return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) [self load];
  return self;
}

- (void)load {

  NSArray* topLevelObjects;
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView"
                                owner:self
                      topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjects];

  NSView* view;
  for (id aView in topLevelObjects) {
    if ([umaVista isKindOfClass:[NSView class]]) {
      view = umaVista;
      break;
    }
  }

  [self addSubview:view];
  view.frame = self.bounds;  

}
```

I create a `NSView` on the main app.

I change that view to the `MyCustomView`.

I run the app. `MyCustomView`'s `initWithCoder` does not run. `initWithFrame` does not run. `awakeFromNib` does not run.

Nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "assign it to the `XIB`'s first responder"? You can't "assign" anything to First Responder, that's a proxy item that represents the dynamic first responder value.

Comment: what do you mean? this is how all tutorials on the web tell.

Comment: Do you mean you assigned it to "File's Owner"?

Comment: ah, sorry, I mean File Owner...

Comment: Closely related (same cause, really): [-awakeFromNib for File's Owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370300/handling-of-awakefromnib-for-the-object-that-is-files-owner/45373876#45373876)

Comment: "File's Owner" isn't actually in the archive, it's just a placeholder.

Comment: so what is the solution for this? Please make it an answer, so I can accept and give you the points and the glory... 

Comment: Add an instance of the view to the nib, and unarchive the nib in the usual way rather than handwriting it.

Comment: this is klingon to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"File's Owner" [as I've written elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370300/handling-of-awakefromnib-for-the-object-that-is-files-owner/45373876#45373876), isn't a real object in the archive. It's a placeholder. When you unpack the nib, a pre-existing object gets used.

It looks like you should just be putting an instance of your custom view into the nib. Don't make it File's Owner, just drag a view out from the object palette and then change its class in the Identity Inspector (right pane, top; press ⌘-⌥-3). Build the subviews in the nib too.

Then get your `NSBundle` to load the nib for you. Your custom view will get `initWithCoder:` and `awakeFromNib`, and you won't have to grovel through the hierarchy to find a particular subview.