# How to set a default value to a UITextField when the application is loaded?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm a Objective-C newbie and I'm currently trying to build an app which has a `UITextField` (called "initial_dose") and I'm wondering how can I set a default value which will be visible straight after the application is loaded.

I kind of know how to set the value but not sure where I need to call this?

```
initial_dose.text = "@myInitialVal";
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    initial_dose.text = @"myInitialVal";
}
```

[Which should I use, -awakeFromNib or -viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377202/which-should-i-use-awakefromnib-or-viewdidload) - for more info.

Comment: Hi Mr-sk, 

I've just tested your suggestion and the app crash :-\

The app is REALLY simple, it has two UITextField and a button.

IBOutlet UITextField *pth_level;
IBOutlet UITextField *initial_dose;

I related each one through the connection panel (Interface Builder) with the File's Owner reference and that's it.

Am I missing something? 

Thank you!!