# add View loaded from xib into a UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xib

I'm trying to add a View created through a xib File into a UIScrollview.

The View looks like that:
[image: View setup in Interface Builder]

What I get is:
[image: The View added to a UIScrollview in code]

The Code I use to add the View to the UIScrollview (which is setup in Storyboard) is:

Initialisation code:

```
NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SpuelungProtokollView" owner:self options:nil];
HPSpuelungProtokollView * spuelungProtokollView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
HPSpuelung * vInfo = pInfo;

// setup Infos
// ... this part is not related to the problem ...

[self setContentView:spuelungProtokollView];
```

and then I do the following in `viewDidLoad:`:

```
[[self scrollView] setContentSize:[[self contentView] frame].size];
[[self scrollView] addSubview:[self contentView]];
[[self contentView] layoutIfNeeded];
```

Has anybody had a similar Problem - know how to properly add a (properly constraint) UIView to UIScrollview?

Thanks in Advance for Answers!

**EDIT**

A strange Side Effect is: the View loads correctly if I put the view Hirarchy is created in `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: What does your awakeFromNib look like?

Comment: I don't have any - what is that function good for? Sorry for beeing a nOOb with xib's until now I did everything with storyboards where I never used this Method

Comment: i added an answer, read up on the protocol on the apple dev site, they have examples as well.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to resolve the Issue - I had to set the Autoresizing Mask of the custom View in `initWithCoder:` like that:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Hope this helps somebody else....

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `awakeFromNib:` to initialize the view.  If you aren't, then it's probably not getting setup properly.

> **NSNibAwaking Protocol Reference:** This informal protocol consists of a
>   single method, awakeFromNib. Classes can implement  this method to
>   initialize state information after objects have been loaded from an
>   Interface Builder archive (nib file).

So, i think you'd want something like the following for your impl:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [[self scrollView] setContentSize:[[self contentView] frame].size];
    [[self scrollView] addSubview:[self contentView]];
    [[self contentView] layoutIfNeeded];
    return;
}
```

`awakeFromNib` is actually special in that it's part of the NSNibAwaking ***informal*** protocol (basically means that your object doesn't have to conform to it). What happens is when an object is loaded from a nib file (.xib) it will be sent this message once all the outlets are connected as long as it implements the awakeFromNib method.

Comment: Since I'm creating the View in `prepareForSegue: sender:` how do I know which function is called first, `viewDidLoad:` - which assures the ScrollView is there - and `awakeFromNib:` - which assures the Nib is loaded correctly?

Comment: look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6303539/1354100) for that question.  ;)  Essentially viewDidLoad is called first.

Comment: Unfortunately according to my testing this is not true - I guess this is because the Methodes are called to indicate the State of different Views - viewDidLoad is called when the Storyboard xib is decompressed and awakeFromNib is called when the container View is ready...

Comment: I just tried to initialize the subview in `viewDidLoad` of the Main view controller in order to be sure of the call order. Even that did not change much.