# Use ViewController to Resize UIImageView specified in NIB

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have created a single view application. In the NIB-file, I have added a UIImageView.

The ViewController.h file sets up the UIImageView:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
```

The ViewController.m looks like this:

```
@implementation NDViewController

@synthesize imgView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ND.png"];
    [imgView setImage:img];
}
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
}
```

And while the `setImage` works perfectly fine, the `setFrame` has no effect.

The original size specified in the NIB remains the one shown; but surely there has to be a way to override the view size?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: awakeFromNib is called before viewDidLoad

Comment: I had read that some subview setups may not be done before viewDidLoad is fired. But moving it into viewDidLoad does not change it, unfortunately :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

put this code in viewDidLoad method .then the resizing works.
And about the real problem and it solution [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302629/viewdidload-and-awakefromnib-timing)

Comment: Thanks, the link really helped my understanding :)