# Explain awakeFromNib and initwithFrame: usage

Tags: objective-c

I am going through the Stanford iPhone dev lectures on iTunes and ran into this in Lecture 5.

We are trying to ensure a redraw will be done when the device rotates.
I have two questions related to this:

1. What is `awakeFromNib`? There's no call to this method in the rest of the code. How was it triggered?
2. What does the codes inside `initwithFrame:` do?

.

```
-(void)setup 
{
      self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setup];
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
     self=[super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
        [self setup];
     }
     return self;
}
```

Comment: This question has some answers over at Quora: [What exactly happens when a view (or subview) is loaded from a nib?](http://www.quora.com/Cocoa-API/What-exactly-happens-when-a-view-or-subview-is-loaded-from-a-nib) and [What is the difference between initWithCoder:, initWithNibName:, and awakeFromNib?](http://www.quora.com/Cocoa-API/What-is-the-difference-between-initWithCoder-initWithNibName-and-awakeFromNib).

Answer (score 24):

`awakeFromNib` is called by `NSBundle` when it finishes loading your nib.

You've actually got two different code paths your code can take when initializing a view, depending on whether it's loaded from a nib or created at runtime.

- If it's loaded from a nib, part of the loading will initialize it by calling `initWithCoder:`, followed by a later call of `awakeFromNib` after all the outlets have been connected.
- If you create the view programmatically, you initialize it with `initWithFrame:` instead (and `awakeFromNib` is never called because it wasn't loaded from a nib).

Comment: Thanks. I'm now clear about the awakeFromNib. What about the self=... What is self? What is super? And whose super are we getting here?

Comment: self is a pointer to the current object (it's implicitly defined for every non-static method). super lets you call the object's superclass's implementation of the current method. The `self = [super init...]` is a convention for how you invoke the superclass's initializer (since it can possibly return a different object). These are fundamental notions in Objective-C and object-oriented programming though, a fair bit beyond the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, initWitFrame will initialize what ever you using with a given rectangular space 
CGRect is the coordinate position. Read on CGRectMake. The basic idea is         `CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)`

for the second half of you question check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/377390/1085186)