# How do I change font for navigation items?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I know this has to be simple, but it's eluding me:

I have code in a UINavigationController that's doing a fine job of setting the font for the title of the navigation bar, along with the background color and the color of the navigation items:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 46/255, green: 99/255, blue: 201/255, alpha: 1.0)
    navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 17)!]

}
```

but I can't get the font for the navigation items to change. I've tried a few things, including (in the same viewDidLoad):

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 17)!], for: UIControlState.normal)`

as well as (in viewDidLoad of one of the ViewControllers using the navbar:)

`self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 17)!], for: UIControlState.normal)`

I have the font in the plist, and am using it successfully in other parts of the project. I assume I'm just trying to do this the wrong way, can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the appearance of all UIBarButtonItems in you UINavigationViewController class:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font!], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

See more details here: [Change font of back navigation bar button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535507/change-font-of-back-navigation-bar-button)

Comment: This worked, but I needed to put it in the App Delegate to catch the first navigator window, using iOS 11 swift 4.0

Answer (score 0):

if `OpenSans` is not in the plist file you would get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

so try

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 46/255, green: 99/255, blue: 201/255, alpha: 1.0)
    navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 17)!]
}
```

[difference between awakeFromNib() and viewDidLoad() in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993079/difference-between-awakefromnib-and-viewdidload-in-swift)