# set frame dynamically

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

i am very confused with the storyboard and custom codes working together, sometimes it works and a lot of times i am trying to figure out why isn't it working

eg i set up a custom view in storyboard and hook up with outlets. when app starts i try to move the custom view around in awakFromNib, but it just won't move... :(

does anyone have solution to this? or can anyone please kindly explain the basics when it comes to layout in the storyboard and dynamically change attributes in code?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modifications on your (Nib-generated) view should be done in

- `viewDidLoad()`
- `viewWillAppear()`
- `viewDidAppear()`

If you need animated changes, you should move your code to the viewDidAppear()-Method,
which is called after the view becomes visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do your animations after `viewDidLoad`. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377202/which-should-i-use-awakefromnib-or-viewdidload) answer, to better understand `awakeFromNib`.