# passing variable when viewcontroller is initialized

Tags: ios, variables, uiviewcontroller

I have a method running when a button is tapped:

```
   let tempVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AwardViewController") as! AwardViewController
   tempVC.currentDocumentPartTitle = currentDocumentPart.title
```

And here is AwardViewController class,

```
class AwardViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    var currentDocumentPartTitle: String!

 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
     //assigning text to UITextView in awakeFromNib method
     //In order to find right textfile, currentDocumentPartTitle is used to search right data in plist.
}
```

The problem is that even if I pass the variable, it returns nil value error in awakeFromNib method saying `currentDocumentPartTitle` is nil. How do I pass a variable before awakeFromNib is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `awakeFromNib()` is performed before the view's properties are allocatable. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/377390/1214800.

Why not simply do what you need to do inside of `viewDidLoad()`?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(currentDocumentPartTitle!) // works!
}
```

Comment: I can't do that since I need to do some configuration for textView before it is allocated in viewcontroller. For my specific situation, it needs to be done in awakeFromNib and that is why I'm having hard time to figure out.

Comment: Then you're probably going to have to write a custom convenience init I think so that it's set on initialization. That, or rewrite what's dependent `awakeFromNib()` (I could see that being necessary for a UIView-based component, but view controllers have `viewDidLoad()` for exactly this reason).

Answer (score 0):

You should put code that copies values of of properties and displays it into your UI in your destination view controller's `viewWillAppear:animated:` method.

So for your `AwardViewController` class, add code to your `viewWillAppear:animated:` that installs the value of `currentDocumentPartTitle` into your UI.

By the way, in the first part of your code you show creating the view controller, and setting the value of `tempVC.currentDocumentPartTitle`, but you don't show any code to display the new view controller. Are you presenting it modally?

Comment: I call "presentViewController" at the end but I forgot to add in the question.