# AwakeFromNib has nil outlets

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my RootViewController, I have IBOutlets. I can access them by `viewWillAppear` but they are all nil in `awakeFromNib()`

I am calling `super.awakeFromNib()`

Why are they all nil? Doesn't the Apple document guarantee that all the outlets from my view controller are initialized when `awakeFromNib` is called?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib

Quote from the apple dev docs:

> When an object receives an `awakeFromNib` message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established.

Comment: Can you post your awakeFromNib() method? Are you putting a breakpoint to test the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which should I use, -awakeFromNib or -viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377202/which-should-i-use-awakefromnib-or-viewdidload)

Comment: Have you connected all outlets correctly ? Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

For a `UIViewController` method `awakeFromNib` is called when the controller is "awake" from Nib file. You should use `viewDidLoad` is you want to interact with outlets.